# JSON object is incorrectly decoded as JSON String(Parson library)

Tags: c, json, azure-iot-hub

I'm using the parson library to decode a json message body sent from a backend (AzureIoTHub direct method call). My string is always decoded as type JSONString instead of JSONObject so I cannot extract and keys and values. I think something is wrong with my string in the payload buffer but I'm stuck on what it is. ANy help is appreciated.

Here are two examples of different json strings stored in payload_buffer variable and neither work.

> "{'device': '65'}"
> JSON Type: 2

or

> "{"device": "3445667"}"
> JSON Type: 2

```
  uint8_t payload_buffer[448];
  JSON_Value *root_value = NULL;
  JSON_Object *root_object = NULL;

  JSON_Value *device_name = NULL;
  const char* device;
    printf("%.*s \r\n", (INT)insert_index, (CHAR *)&payload_buffer );

    root_value = json_parse_string((const char *)&payload_buffer[0]);
    if (root_value != NULL)
    {
      if (json_value_get_type(root_value) == JSONObject)
      {
    root_object=json_value_get_object(root_value);

    device_name = json_object_dotget_value (root_object, "device");
    device = json_value_get_string(device_name);
    if (device != NULL)
    {
      printf("device: %s", device );
    }
      }
      else
      {
    printf("JSON Type: %u \r\n", json_value_get_type(root_value));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are the double quotes present at the start and end of the string being parsed?  If so, you are getting the correct result.  It matters critically what bytes are passed to the parser.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I believe they are present and are being parsed. If I understand what you are saying then the opening and closing quotes in the JSON string are causing the whole string to be interpreted as a JSONString and not a JSONObject.  I assume I have to find a way to strip the opening and closing quotes from my payload before calling the json_parse_string(). Is that correct?

Comment: That is my suggestion, certainly.  It's perfectly valid for a JSON document to contain just a string between double quotes — and that's a JSON string, of course.  And given that the first character is a double quote, that's all your document can contain.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Your suggestion solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to have helped.  I'll not submit an answer — yours is fine.

Answer (score 2):

For parson library to interpret a buffer as a JSONObject and not a JSONString you cannot have the buffer start and end with **"** character. Once I edited my buffer to this

> {"device": "3445667"}

my code was able to parse the JSON object correctly.